# font looks different on website than on Google font website

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, google-fonts

I am currently trying to use the 'Josefin Sans' font in a website I am developing using TailwindCSS, NextJS and Typescript. The font looks noticeably different on my website than on my Figma design wireframe and the Google fonts website. I have attached two images to show the difference in appearance [font in Google fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTqhS.png), [font in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqmFT.png).

Can anyone give an explanation on why this is happening and/or a solution on how to fix it?

I have imported the font from google using the @import option

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Red+Hat+Display&family=Red+Hat+Text:wght@400;500&display=swap');
```

and extending it in `tailwind.config.ts`:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        josefin: ["Josefin Sans", "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
  },
```

and using it as so: `<p className='font-josefin text-7xl font-normal text-black text-center'>Example</p>`

Answer (score 0):

The key should be sans.not josefin

```
fontFamily:{
    sans: ["Josefin Sans", "sans-serif"]
}
```